# Correct use of OOP in a three-layered c# asp.net database application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, three-tier

I'm starting C# and would like to know if there is any problem in approach below:

[image]

Briefly, in the layers there would be instances similar to the following:

**UI**

```
var userBll = _userBll.SaveUser(dtoUser);
```

**BLL**

```
// Validations and other business rules
return _userDal.SaveUser (dtoUser); // Request DAL
```

**DAL**

```
// Return the saved user to the database
return userDb;
```

Is there a problem with this kind of approach, in which the UserBll class would contain the "SaveUser" method? Would not it be correct to have a User class responsible for calling the Save method? Something like:

```
var user = new User();
user.SaveUser()
```

In this case would there be a redundancy between the User object class and the UserDTO data transport class?

Sorry if this may sound like a silly question, but it really confuses me.

Comment: Did you do some reading up? Because as it is that isa BROAD topic - but it is also one that has a ton of books written about it and public posts arguing any approach. As per site rules, specific questions would be welcome here - but as it is, I am not going to write a multi page answer.

Comment: It seems like you are conflating “tiers” with “layers”.

Comment: This approach makes sense **IFF** you use several **UI** to access the same BLL and several business logic which use the same DAL.

Comment: If you'd have `user.SaveUser()` which would probably call database then imagine saving 1000 users at once. It would take a lot of time with 1000 queries.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev Would not it make sense for ease of maintenance? What about providing a clear division of responsibilities? But my main question would be whether using a method (behavior) in a business class would be a break in concept in OOP. The principle of doubt is: the "Save" behavior should not be in a User class instead of directly in the UserBll class

Comment: @Marcoscdoni Theoretically, you can have `User.Save()` method in BLL which calls some method in DAL (and be ignorant/agnostic what DAL does). Even more, DAL method can be polymorphic and depend on underlying data source (i.e. sql server, mySQL, or whatever). In this case it **does** make sense. Else the multilayer approach just creates a chain of transformations and potentially may damage performance. Again, It Depends.

Answer (score 0):

The DAL is merely an abstraction over the underlying data provider. The BLL doesn't know of what's going on, just knows it wants to save a user, given the validation is successful.

I therefore believe the approach containing `_userDal.SaveUser (dtoUser)` is more appropriate for such a thing. But in my own apps, I usually have another assembly for common/shared items. Something like your `dtoUser`. I don't like direct dependencies between UI and DAL in 3-layered apps.